# FFMPEG: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'format')

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, react-dropzone

I am currently to convert a video file to produce a thumbnail through ffmpeg, react-dropzone, and express. However I keep getting a error of "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'format')" in my console. For some reason it can not read the "metadata.format.duration" in my program, I have checked if ffmpeg is properly installed by running the ffmpeg --version in my console, and I get all the details, along with ffprobe --version as well.

Here is my code:
upload.js

```
router.post("/thumbnail", (req, res) => {
    let thumbsFilePath ="";
    let fileDuration ="";

    // req.body.filepath
    ffmpeg.ffprobe(req.body.filepath, function(err, metadata){
        console.dir(metadata);
        console.log(metadata.format.duration);

        fileDuration = metadata.format.duration;
    })

    ffmpeg(req.body.filepath) //req.body.filepath
    .on('filenames', function (filenames) {
        console.log('Will generate ' + filenames.join(', '))
        console.log(filenames);
        thumbsFilePath = "./uploads/thumbnails/" + filenames[0];
        
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Screenshots taken');
        return res.json({ success: true, thumbsFilePath: thumbsFilePath, fileDuration: fileDuration})
    })
    .screenshots({
        // Will take screens at 20%, 40%, 60% and 80% of the video
        count: 3,
        folder: './uploads/thumbnails',
        size:'320x240',
        // %b input basename ( filename w/o extension )
        filename:'thumbnail-%b.png'
    });
})
```

FrontEnd drop code:
AddVideo.js

```
const onDrop = (files) => {

        let formData = new FormData();
        const config = {
            header: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
        }
        console.log(files)
        formData.append("file", files[0])

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/upload/uploadfiles', formData, config)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {

                    let variable = {
                        filePath: response.data.filePath,
                        fileName: response.data.fileName
                    }
                    setFilePath(response.data.filePath)

                    //gerenate thumbnail with this filepath ! 

                    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/upload/thumbnail', variable)
                        .then(response => {
                            if (response.data.success) {
                                setDuration(response.data.fileDuration)
                                setThumbnail(response.data.thumbsFilePath)
                            } else {
                                alert('Failed to make the thumbnails');
                            }
                        })


                } else {
                    alert('failed to save the video in server')
                }
            })

    }

    return (
        <div style={{ maxWidth: '700px', margin: '2rem auto' }}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
                {/* <Title level={2} > Upload Video</Title> */}
            </div>

            <FormControl>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <Dropzone
                        onDrop={onDrop}
                        multiple={false}
                        maxSize={800000000}>
                        {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                            <div style={{ width: '300px', height: '240px', border: '1px solid lightgray', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
                                {...getRootProps()}
                            >
                                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                                <Icon type="plus" style={{ fontSize: '3rem' }} />

                            </div>
                        )}
                    </Dropzone>
            </div>
            </FormControl>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The video I am trying to upload is a mp4 file. I am using fluent-ffmpeg as a dependency.